# xml.etree.ElementTree module .set() changes the existing property sequence

Tags: python, xml, scripting, xml-parsing, xml.etree

To simplify my question

my xml:

```
<a><b RANGE1="32,127", RANGE2="3,17", RANGE3="2,2", RANGE17="2,12",RANGE27="3,3" /></a>
```

I want to add property RANGE10="5,5"

I used below comment from xml.etree.ElementTree python module

```
element.set('RANGE10', '5,5')
```

it gives like

```
<b RANGE1="32,127", RANGE10="5,5", RANGE17="2,12", RANGE2="3,17",RANGE27="3,3",RANGE3="2,2"/>
```

i.e it automatically arrange themselves in ascending order like RANGE1,RANGE10,RANGE17,RANGE2,RANGE27,RANGE3 similiarly..

But i want to append my input at end without disturbing existing order like below,

```
<b RANGE1="32,127", RANGE2="3,17", RANGE3="2,2", RANGE17="2,12",RANGE27="3,3", RANGE10="5,5"/>
```

what needs to be done?. Thanks